# Coefficients of product of polynomials of degree 1

Tags: polynomials, factorial, products

I have the following equations:
\begin{aligned}
(x+x_1)(x+x_2)&=x^2+(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2\\
(x+x_1)(x+x_2)(x+x_3)&= x^3+(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x+x_1x_2x_3\\
(x+x_1)(x+x_2)(x+x_3)(x+x_4)&=x^4+(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)x^3\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_3+x_3x_4)x^2\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +(x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)x\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +x_1x_2x_3x_4\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
(x+x_1)(x+x_2)\cdots(x+x_{n-1})(x+x_n)&=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1x+c_0
\end{aligned}
Where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are known. My question is if there is a general formula to calculate all of the coefficients $c_i$. At the moment I only know that $c_n=1$ and $c_0=\prod\limits^n_{i=1}x_i$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact. The generating function of the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $n$ variables is
$$S_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+x_ix)}=\sum_{i=0}^n{e_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)x^i}$$
where
$$e_0(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1$$
and
$$e_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq p_1<\cdots<p_i\leq n}{x_{p_1}\cdots x_{p_i}}$$
It's simply the sum over all subsets of the variables with $i$ elements of the product of the variables in the subset.

This is not quite your product. Your product is
$$x^nS_n\left(\frac1x\right)$$
Thus the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ is $e_i$.